# Ubuntu 20.04 Joint Displays

Tags: 20.04, display

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and have just added a second monitor. On the current configuration the two monitors are treated as a single monitor with screens stretching across the two monitors. This is sub-optimal. For example, this sometimes means clicking on a link means that the options appear on the other screen and expanding a window means that it bleeds across both screens. What I want is for the two screens to be treated as separate screens as happened in, for example, 18.04. The change in functionality is reflected in the change of the joint display icon which has changed from 18.04 [18.04 Joint Display icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGSEN.png) to 20.04 [20.04 Joint Display icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf4X6.png). Is there any way to change the joint display functionality back to two screens from a single screen?

Edit: I am using nvidia-driver-450 after the nouveau driver failed to recognise the second screen at all.

Edit: Swapping the driver up to nvidia-driver-470 seems to have resolved the issue.